# PowerShell AD query vs C# AD Query - Speed

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I'm learning C# and am a novice. Please be patient with me.

I've developed an app in C# to search for users, groups, and group members in AD by Piping PowerShell commands into it.

Now I'm trying to use DirectoryServices in C# to get the same results, however the time it take to get the same results back is much longer than it is in PowerShell.

**Here is what I am doing now with DirectoryServices for a quick test:**

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string textbox = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Columns.Clear();
            try
            {
                // Bind to the object for which to retrieve property data.
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("");
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

                ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Group)(cn="+ textbox + "))";

                ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

                SearchResultCollection rsAll = ds.FindAll();

                listView1.Columns.Add("samsaccountname");

                string samsaccountname = "";

                foreach (SearchResult searchresult in rsAll)
                {

                    if (searchresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
                    { samsaccountname = searchresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString(); }
                    else { samsaccountname = ""; }

                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(samsaccountname);
                    //lvi.SubItems.Add(givenName);
                    //lvi.SubItems.Add(sn);
                    //lvi.SubItems.Add(mail);
                    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

                }

                listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);

            }
            catch
            {
                // Add error handling.
            }
        }
```

**Here is what I did in PowerShell + C#**

```
private string SearchDLScript(string searchDL)
{

    listViewSearchDL.Items.Clear();
    listViewSearchDL.Columns.Clear();
    listViewSearchDL.Columns.Add("");
    listViewSearchDL.Items.Add("Loading list, please wait.");
    listViewSearchDL.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

    if (textSearchDL.Text.Length < 8)
    {
        listViewSearchDL.Items.Add("Hint: The more you type, the quicker the seach.");
        listViewSearchDL.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }

    string rbName = "";
    if (radioButtonDisplayName.Checked == true)
    {
        rbName = "DisplayName";
    } else if (radioButtonAlias.Checked == true)
    {
        rbName = "SamAccountName";
    }

    string searchDLScriptCommand = @"Import-Module ActiveDirectory
        Get-ADGroup -Filter '"+rbName+ @" -Like """ + searchDL + @"*"" ' -Properties * | Select-Object DisplayName,SamAccountName | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1";
    string scriptOutput = RunPowerShellCommands.RunPowerShellCode(searchDLScriptCommand);
    string[] strArr = scriptOutput.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    strArr = strArr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

    listViewSearchDL.Columns.Clear();
    listViewSearchDL.Items.Clear();
    listViewSearchDL.Columns.Add("Display Name");
    listViewSearchDL.Columns.Add("Alias");

    foreach (string user in strArr)
    {
        string userDetails = user.Replace("\"", "");
        string[] columns = userDetails.Split(',');
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(columns[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < columns.Count(); i++)
        {
            lvi.SubItems.Add(columns[i]);
        }

        listViewSearchDL.Items.Add(lvi);
    }

    if (scriptOutput == "\r\n")
    {
        listViewSearchDL.Items.Clear();
        listViewSearchDL.Columns.Clear();
        listViewSearchDL.Columns.Add("");
        listViewSearchDL.Items.Add("There are no records");
    }

    listViewSearchDL.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
    listViewSearchDL.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);


    return "scriptOutput";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the C# sample you implicitly perform two extra lookups *per object* returned by the DirectorySearcher, by calling `GetDirectoryEntry()`:

```
foreach (SearchResult searchresult in rsAll)
{
    if (searchresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
    { samsaccountname = searchresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString(); }
    else { samsaccountname = ""; }

    // and then updating the listview
}
```

[The documentation for `GetDirectoryEntry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) even warns you about this:

> **Note**
>   Calling GetDirectoryEntry on each SearchResult returned through DirectorySearcher can be slow.

---

What you'd want to do is add the list of property names that you'll need to the searcher (this is what the `Get-AD* -Properties` parameter does in the background), and have them returned after the very first search:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

// do this before calling FindAll()
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname")
```

and then when you process the search results, grab the property value directly from each search result instead of calling `GetDirectoryEntry()` again:

```
foreach (SearchResult searchresult in rsAll)
{
    if (searchresult.Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
    { 
        samsaccountname = searchresult.Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString(); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        samsaccountname = ""; 
    }

    // and then updating the listview
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias,Thank for this, but changing the code to the above (without GetDirectoryEntry()) gives me an error of "ResultPropertyValueCollection" does not contain a definition of "Value"....
Am I missing something in the code?